# Issue with moment.js method: moment.tz.guess() in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, timezone, momentjs

I am having an issue with comparing zone values in my code, it's sort of a bug from what i understand.

**My requirement**: compare the timezone we get from moment with the one i have in array and set it somewhere.
I get value from moment.js using **moment.tz.guess()** and i compare it with the timezones value/name i have present in my local array.

**Issue Faced**: Only in case of Google Chrome browser, i am getting value of **moment.tz.guess()** as **Asia/Calcutta** whereas in case of Firefox and IE/Edge, i am getting **Asia/Kolkata**.

My local array has value/name as Asia/Kolkata, hence, i am not able to compare the values in Chrome browser, but i am able to get correct comparison in other mentioned browsers.

This is a timezone specific issue as earlier Asia/Kolkata was Asia/Calcutta.

Also, i am using latest version of moment.js and have the latest versions of the browsers in my system installed, so i'm not sure where the issue is.
Also, i'm using angularJS 1.6 as my main framework for UI.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is a simple Fiddle of the actual issue at my side what comes as moment.tz.guess()

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
<script>
var timezone = moment.tz.guess();
alert(timezone);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wcu21kr5/3125/

it gives different values in Chrome vs Firefox (Calcutta vs Kolkata), the correct and latest one Kolkata

For the time being, in my code, what i have done is i have directly compared the string value from my array and the one i get from moment.tz.guess() and then consider them as equal and then proceed.

This way my application works, but it's sort of a hard code check for a specific case, what if there's change in other timezone city names? adding new city each time isn't a good option

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Chrome behavior that leads to Moment making an incorrect guess.  The Moment development team is uninterested in developing a workaround.  I'd hesitate to call this a bug as all the specs allow for returning deprecated TZs, but it's definitely a deficiency in the spec.  The Moment developers believe that most consumers should be fine with the deprecated TZ.

https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3852

Comment: I did earlier go through the provided github link, but i couldn't come to any conclusion about the resolution.
Is there any workaround possible? without using any extra or new js library?